# SQL Create new row as a sum of multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Supposing I have the following rows:

```
VARIABLENAME   YYYYMM   XXXXYY   DATAOBS
variable_1   | 201101 | 111100 | 20
variable_2   | 201101 | 111100 | 20
variable_1   | 201102 | 111100 | 30
variable_2   | 201102 | 111100 | 30
variable_1   | 201101 | 222211 | 20
variable_2   | 201101 | 222211 | 20
variable_1   | 201102 | 222211 | 30
variable_2   | 201102 | 222211 | 30
```

I would like to know how to get the result:

```
VARIABLENAME      YYYYMM    XXXXYY   DATAOBS
variables_1and2 | 201101  | 111100 | 40
variables_1and2 | 201102  | 111100 | 60
variables_1and2 | 201101  | 222211 | 40
variables_1and2 | 201102  | 222211 | 60
```

where all the **DATAOBS** in rows containing **variable_1** and **variable_2** within each respective **YYYYMM** within in each respective **XXXXYY** are added and placed  in a new row, **variables_1and2**, still within their respective **YYYYMM** and respective **XXXXYY**.

If it's necessary to know, there are several hundred different YYYYMM and XXXXYY in the actual data I'm dealing with.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you just want

```
SELECT 'variables_1and2' variablename,
       yyyymm,
       xxxxyy,
       sum(dataobs) dataobs
  FROM your_table
 WHERE variablename in ('variable_1', 'variable_2' )
 GROUP BY yyyymm, xxxxyy
```

If the intention is to insert these rows back into your table, you'd need an `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO your_table( variablename, yyyymm, xxxxyy, dataobs )
  SELECT 'variables_1and2' variablename,
         yyyymm,
         xxxxyy,
         sum(dataobs) dataobs
    FROM your_table
   WHERE variablename in ('variable_1', 'variable_2' )
   GROUP BY yyyymm, xxxxyy
```

Of course, it would be very unusual for it to make sense to store both detail and aggregate data in the same table.  That would generally be a poor design.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but if there are no rows called **variables_1and2** yet, will this create them?

Comment: @user1521480 - It creates `variables_1and2` rows in the result set.  If you want to insert these rows back into the table, you'd need to `INSERT` the results from the `SELECT` into the table.  I edited my answer to include this option as well.  It would be very rare that it would really make sense to store aggregate and detail data in the same table.

Comment: In this case it is necessary. Also thank you very much for your quick response!

Comment: @user1521480 - If it is necessary, that generally implies that the data model itself is flawed.  It's possible that this is a reasonable tactical hack until the data model can be fixed and/or a more appropriate method of storing aggregate data is identified (such as using materialized views).  It seems very unlikely that this is the right approach long term.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Oracle are you using?  You can do (in 10g):

```
select wm_concat(variablename),yyyymm,xxxxyy, sum(dataobs) dataobs
from table
group by yyyymm,xxxxyy
```

If you have 11g release 2, you can use `list_agg(variablename,',')`